# Iterator is adding the wrong address

Tags: java, data-structures, iterator, iteration

In my program I've added an ArrayList of another class type but when I iterate the list I get a wrong address. 
For example my code is

```
    ArrayList<Student> stdntList = new ArrayList<Student>();
    stdntList.add(new Student("Candace","633501"));
    stdntList.add(new Student("Curtis ","634572"));
    stdntList.add(new Student("Amber","623343"));
    System.out.println(stdntList);

    Iterator itr = stdntList.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext())
    {
        System.out.println("Student: " + itr.next());
    }
```

and my output is

```
Student Name: Candace Student ID633501
Student Name: Curtis  Student ID634572
Student Name: Amber Student ID623343
[Student@659e0bfd, Student@2a139a55, Student@15db9742]
Student: Student@659e0bfd
Student: Student@2a139a55
Student: Student@15db9742
```

Comment: Please disambiguate: what do you mean by "address"? Ideally, you should provide the desired output as part of the question.

Answer (score 2):

In order to take the address, you should maybe print something like this `System.out.println("Student: " + itr.next().getAddress());`

As it is now, it prints everything it is on *.toString()* method. You have to override this method in order to print the address by calling only the reference to the class.